# Comparison and testing multinomial coefficients

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, multinomial-distribution

Straight to the problem I want to test the hypothesis that two coefficients of multinomial regression model are equal between them. For example, considering a model where Y is 3 level categorical variable: A, B, C, and two covariates, X1 and X2 both dichotomous, we will have 6 coefficients. (A is the baseline of Y and X1=0 X2=0 is the baseline for covariates)

```
-              B        C
Intercept      c1       c2
X1             c3       c4
X2             c5       c6
```

Through the standard error of the coefficients (in a rough way) I can test the hypotesis that any of the coefficients are equal to the underlined ones in the baseline (the log odds ratios of A), but how can I test the hypotesis that c3=c4?
Last thing I'm an R user.